# How to find the number of options for choosing numbers from $a_1, a_2, a_3, ... a_n$ such that their sum was equal to $k$

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, probability-theory, number-theory, discrete-mathematics

Let our numbers $2, 5, 6, 7, 10, 15$ and $k = 15$. I need to find the number of possible options for choosing numbers that form a total of 15. It's $(5, 10), (2, 7 ,6), (15)$. So the answer is 3.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: This looks to me as an example where a simple [brute force search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brute-force_search) would yield the result quickly. It is a different story if you have *many* numbers: the [Knapsack problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem) is [NP-complete](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP-completeness) which means that, as of today ([P vs NP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P_versus_NP_problem) not being solved) there is no efficient algorithm to solve the general case. If there is some regularity in the given numbers, then there may be shortcuts.

Comment: As for the manual solution: either $15$ is in the set (and we are done), or $10$ is in the set (and then it is obvious that $6$ and $7$ can't be, and the only way to get additional $5$ is to pick $5$), or $7$ is in the set (and then you have to make up $8$ out of $2,5,6$, which is only possible as $2+6$) or neither $15,10,7$ are in the set (but this is not possible because all the remaining numbers only add up to $13$). Basically - distinguish cases (with the advice to start with the biggest number as this usually yields the solution quicker!)

Comment: I wonder if 2,2,2,2,2,5 counts as a solution (i.e., can we reuse numbers?).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you know generating functions?

Look at the polynomial
$$
P(x) = \prod_{i=1}^n(1+x^{a_i}) 
$$
The coefficient of $x^k$ is the number of possible choices for $k$ as a sum of $a_i$.